# Javascript document.onclick fires immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wrote this:

```
      document.getElementById("seite7_pbildchat").onclick = function() {seite5_wechseln(pemail);};
```

So i want add an onclick eventlistener to the elemt immediately fires. So the function is calles without an user click. It should only be fired when the user is clicking it.

Comment: Without user click but fired when user is clicking? Which one is it?

Comment: it is fire WITHOUT a user click and it should be fired WITH a user click

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer your question. Try replacing you code with `document.getElementById("seite7_pbildchat").onclick = alert('got click');` and tell us what happens.

Comment: function setData(){
 seite5_wechseln(pemail);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  seite5_wechseln(pemail);
  
   document.getElementById("seite7_pbildchat").onclick = function() {setData()};
});

Comment: I note that you have `jquery` in the tags for the question. I also note that you are not using jQuery's event handling. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
        function setData(){
         seite5_wechseln(pemail);
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
         // initializing on load
          setData()
// defining on id click 
          $('#seite7_pbildchat').on('click',function(){
            setData()
          });
           // if u want to trigger manually   
            $('#seite7_pbildchat').trigger('click');
        });
```